# Drag and drop file upload doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, html, upload, drag-and-drop

I used the JavaScript drag and drop script explained [here](http://html5doctor.com/drag-and-drop-to-server/) and PHP upload script [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

I changed XHR request to upload.php in the JS code. And the progress can go to 100%. But I can't see the uploaded image in the /upload folder.

[Here is my test files](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B97QiW_j7pmBTThHWU00ZmVhSWM).

Comment: Is the folder write-able with proper permissions? Because it worked fine for me. If you run your script from your `root`, then create a sub-folder called `upload` if it doesn't already exist and chmod it to either 755 or 777.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to upload a file bigger than 20kb, it won't work because your `upload.php` file is set to 20,000 bytes. I just tried it with a bigger file and it does show the upload progress bar, but the file doesn't make it into the upload folder. So that may be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After successfully testing with your [**test files**](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B97QiW_j7pmBTThHWU00ZmVhSWM), am under the impression that you are trying to upload a file larger than `20kb` using the same settings in `upload.php`.

This line in `upload.php`

```
($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
```

prevents to upload files larger than that, being 20,000 bytes or 20kb.

**Possible Solution:** 
Increase the amount to `200000` for testing and choose another file measuring approx. 200,000 bytes or 200kb and make sure the folder is writeable, chmod 755 or 777.

> And the progress can go to 100%. But I can't see the uploaded image in the /upload folder.

I just tried it with a bigger file and it does show the upload progress bar, but the file doesn't make it into the upload folder. So that may be the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it turned out to be the file size limit, which caused the issue.